GCC bogus "may be used uninitialized " warning starting with version 11
In our codebase we have code that boils down to the following (trying to use dynamic stack allocation instead of heap allocation):
#include <memory>
#include <alloca.h>

void f(long long const* data, size_t len);

void h(int const* data, size_t len)
{
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> heapBuff;

  auto nbytes = len * sizeof(long long);
  long long* arr;                                                 
  if (nbytes <= 1024) {                          
    arr = reinterpret_cast<long long*>(alloca(nbytes));
  }
  else {
    heapBuff.reset(new char[nbytes]);
    arr = reinterpret_cast<long long*>(heapBuff.get());
  }

  for (size_t i=0; i < len; ++i)
    arr[i]=data[i];

  f(arr, len);
}

(complete example in Compiler Explorer), and compilation results in a "may be used uninitialized" warning in GCC starting with version 11.
/app/h.cpp: In function 'void h(const int*, size_t)':
/app/h.cpp:23:4: warning: 'arr' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   23 |   f(arr, len);
      |   ~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /app/h.cpp:2:
/app/f.hpp:4:6: note: by argument 1 of type 'const long long int*' to 'void f(const long long int*, size_t)' declared here
    4 | void f(long long const* data, size_t len);
      |      ^

Clang or earlier versions of GCC do not produce this warning.
To my eye, there is no path leading to the arr pointer being uninitialized, and the code is so simple that the compiler should have no problem figuring it out. Am I missing something?
One curious thing is that replacing alloca() with malloc() does not affect the warning, but replacing it with some non-inlined void* allocate(size_t) function removes the warning.

This arr = reinterpret_cast<long long*>... might create UB if arr  is deferenced.  If so, the compiler is allowed to assume that the paths that create UB never happen.

arr = reinterpret_cast<long long*>(alloca(nbytes)); doesn't actually create anything, it just allocates memory.  All of the elements in the "array" are uninitialized (this is for pre C++20)

The link to godbolt seems broken (Error 404)

Do you have the same problem if you use std::uninitialized_copy instead of a manual loop?

Code that compiles and has compiled for years (and even seems to run and pass tests) is still not necessarily correct C++ code. Code with UB can often "suddenly" start breaking down when you switch compiler settings, compiler versions or compilers.
The problem can even be somewhere totally else (not in the code you show). E.g. if data  passed to h is a nullptr then that is UB too.

@Homer512 : I have fixed the link, thanks for pointing it out.

@NathanOliver, the elements of the array are initialized in the loop that follows the memory allocation, and, if I understand it correctly, the compiler is complaining about the pointer being uninitialized, not what it points to.

@RichardCritten, I don't understand where UB is here. ASFAIK casting a void* to some other pointer is not UB. How else would one allocate memory for an object? All allocation functions return a void*.  Just removing the heapBuff.reset(new char[nbytes]); line in the example gets rid of the warning, even though it makes the code blatantly wrong.

@akryukov> that reinterpret_cast is illegal. To be precise, dereferencing the result of that cast is undefined behavior. You need to actually create long long objects inside the allocated storage. Better yet, ditch alloca and use an allocation method that will do that for you.

If you are dead set on alloca, say because you interact with some C api and you cannot change, at least you should use std::start_lifetime_as_array to create the array of long long at the address returned by alloca.

@akryukov They are not.  Pre C++20, the alloc family of functions only gives you memory, there are no objects in that memory.  You would need to use placement new to start the lifetime of each element in the array. You don't do that so arr[i]=data[i]; technically has undefined behavior since you are writing to objects that do not exist.

@RemyLebeau, std::uninitialized_copy gives the same result - with a warning

-Wmaybe-uninitialized is the worst GCC warning and you should just disable it.

@spectras, start_lifetime... things are still in a distant future for me, I am still trying to migrate to c++20.

@NathanOliver, replacing the assignment with new (arr + i) long long (data[i]); gives exactly the same result. It's probably just a longer way of writing std::uninitialized_copy and does exactly what the simple assignment does for such trivial types like int.

@BrianBi, you may be right, but I still would like to understand GCC`s "reasoning" that results in this warning, even if it's wrong.

@akryukov you will likely have to look at the actual machine code the compiler produces to see how the compiler decided to use arr and if there are any code paths that can lead to it being undefined.

@RemyLebeau With my level of understanding assembly, I was hoping to avoid this, but it looks like that's next on the way to enlightenment. Another indication of this is that the warning is not produced at -O0 and -O1 optimization levels.

First of, I can see six minor issues that are wrong with the code:

Technically new char[nbytes] is not able to implicitly create an array of long long objects nested in the char array. Consequently accessing through the result of reinterpret_cast<long long*> has undefined behavior. This can be easily remedied by replacing char with unsigned char or std::byte. In both cases starting the lifetime of an array of that type also implicitly creates objects (of implicit-lifetime type) nested in the array.

std::unique_ptr::get will return a pointer to the first array element, not a pointer to any nested long long object (assuming any was created implicitly). Therefore you need an extra std::launder call after reinterpret_cast. (There is currently a proposal to change the standard so that this launder call is no longer necessary.)

It is not clear whether alloca also implicitly creates objects. Since this is a non-standard function, the standard obviously has nothing to say about it and I doubt that any documentation will make a determination on that. However, the only behavior that makes sense to me in practice is that it does implicitly create objects. Presumably it then also returns a pointer to such an implicitly-created object.

len * sizeof(long long) can wrap-around when the exact result is larger than the largest representable value of size_t. In that case, in the loop, arr[i]=data[i] will eventually access arr out-of-bounds, causing undefined behavior.

Because alloca is not standardized, it is not obvious that it will return memory suitably aligned for long long. The GCC documentation for __builtin_alloca says that the memory will be aligned to __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__, which should be large enough to store all non-overaligned types.

Again, because alloca is not standardized, it is not obvious what it will return if the size argument is 0. Unfortunately the GCC documentation for __builtin_alloca doesn't say. From my testing it seems that the stack pointer is returned, although there was some unusual behavior when trying to return the pointer from the function.


However, I do not really see any connection to the warning GCC produces. Even simplifying the example to
void* arr = alloca(10);
f(arr, 0);

GCC still complains (https://godbolt.org/z/vhnr3EaMr).
Interestingly, if you store anything to the memory, then GCC stops complaining (https://godbolt.org/z/x31Gacdrb).
So I suspect that GCC is not happy with the len == 0 case where nothing can be written to the allocated (zero-size) memory. An indication for this is that adding an early return on len == 0 gets rid of the warning.
And I think the reason that the warning checks whether something is written to the memory is that you pass it as const pointer, which indicates that the function f will (only) read from the memory. If nothing was written to it, then nothing can be read from it. If you make the parameter non-const the warning is gone as well.

"Technically new char[nbytes] is not able to implicitly create an array of long long objects nested in the char array."  Yes it is. long long is a scalar, and therefore has implicit-lifetime, and malloc et.all are considered to start the lifetime in the allocated storage. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object
So points #1, #2, and #3 are incorrect.  But your final point about the size=0 case is almost certainly correct.

@MooingDuck operator new does implicitly create objects, but the new expression then places a char array at the same memory location afterwards, which must end the lifetime of any such implicitly-created object because of storage reuse. And the need for std::launder is independent of the implicit object creation issue because new is explicitly specified to return a pointer to the first element of the created array, not any object it provides storage for, see the linked paper.

Well, the short godbolt links created yesterday don't seem to work for some reason, so I can't really see your tweaks. It could be a problem with the IDE mode.

I think most of the debate about the heap storage can be put aside by using std::unique_ptr<long long[]> and new long long[len]. This does not change anything warnings-wize (https://godbolt.org/z/oY84qc4MY).

An early return if (len == 0) indeed gets rid of the warning, and that's what I'm going to do.
Curiously, std::launder(reinterpret_cast<long long*>(alloca(nbytes))) without an early return also does the trick (https://godbolt.org/z/f4aedfz7x)
Unconditional use of alloca() without laundering on early return gets rid of the warning as well (https://godbolt.org/z/cMnx9bosx), though that's not what the code tries to do.

@user17732522: You're correct about operator new, but OP isn't using operator new. OP is using alloca, which (presumaly) follows the same rules as malloc, which does implicitly create the long longs.
